# error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are

Tags: c++, http, if-statement, get

I'm trying to compile code for parsing json.

Code part:

```
        if (response.status != 200){
            std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
```

An error appears in

```
   10 |         if (response.status != 200){
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~
      |                      |         |
      |                      |         int
      |                      const http::Status
```

use include https://github.com/elnormous/HTTPRequest

Tried to put double brackets on response.status()

example

```
        if (response.status() != 200){
            std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
```

Also

```
if ((response.status) != http::OK)
```

Did not help

Comment: All your attempts cause different errors, but you show only the first one. What prevents you from looking at the struct `Status` in the header file HTTPRequest.hpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (response.status.code != 200)
```

Or

```
if (response.status.code != http::Status::Code::Ok)
```